# Error in MODISTools in R

Tags: r

I have this error in R:

> Error in GetProducts() : Application error
>
> In addition: Warning message: package ‘MODISTools’ was built under R version 3.2.3

Can you help me?

Comment: What version of R are you using, and where did you get MODISTools?

Comment: I am using 3.2.2 R version. I installed MODISTools package from R's install tools.

Comment: One possible source of errors is the recently instated requirement for login info when programmetically downloading MODIS data. This could potentially cause some unexpected errors for a package like MODISTools. I don't know if this is the case here, but it should atleast be considered.

Comment: You know where i can confirm that? I have installed the 3.3.1 Version, but the error continue.

Answer (score 1):

This error has been fixed in the latest version of MODISTools, v0.95.0. There is no login info required. The error was caused by ORNL DAAC moving the web service end point. You'll need to update to the latest MODISTools version, then it should work as normal.

Comment: Can you add a GIT url or the method for update, in case `install.packages()`doesn't do the job